# Having a solution file ASP/NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I was wondering is there any advantage to creating a Visual Studio solution file for a ASP.NET web page.

I'm working on a project with others and they have no Visual Studio solution file they just open the web page.

Can anyone offer advice?

Thanks Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is. by creating a solution you dont have to do the hassle of going to File > Open Website > browse and select the folder of the site. instead double clicking the sln file is faster. opened files session is also saved whenever you re-opened the solution

Answer (score 0):

And you can choose another project and make them work together, by showimg one of them as other one's reference, etc.

But technically, no there is not any technical advantage beside easier usage and user-friendly interface.